# Beautiful Soup and improper lists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull data out of a crappy application that stores its data in HTML.  I have a section of code that looks like this:

```
<span id="blah">
  item 1 <br />
  item 2 <br />
  item 3 <br />
</span>
```

I can find the data with beautiful soup, but when I use the .text operator, it returns the contents as `item 1item 2item 3`.

Any ideas on how to get it where 
 is returned as '\n' so I can break it up by lines?

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.strings` to get all of the separate text items within an element (or `.stripped_strings` to have surrounding whitespace automatically stripped from each).

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings